# Create a repo using Grit

Tags: ruby, git, grit

Is there a way to create a branch in a repo using Grit?  I can't seem to find a way in the docs nor is there any reference I can find on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that some of Grit shells out already, and that [`Grit#method_missing`](http://grit.rubyforge.org/classes/Grit/Git.html#M000255) explicitly shells out, it looks like you could do:

```
git.branch({},"branchname")
git.checkout({},"branchname") # If you like
```

Set [extra options](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) as appropriate.